# Symfony2 vendors install

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony

I'm trying to setup and create new bundle with symfony2, but getting so much error almost every step.

I'm download symfony and run this command;

`php bin/vendors install`

`> Installing/Updating swiftmailer
Cloning into /var/www/Symfony/vendor/swiftmailer...

...

...

...

 [ErrorException]

  Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::iNFO in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php line 103`

what is the problem? what should I do?

Comment: Obviously, the problem seems to be the lowercased 'i' in iNFO, but I don't know yet what you could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error reason is Turkish system language. so in Turkish language "i" upper case "İ" and "I" lowercase "ı". I'm change my system language to English and problem solved.

Comment: I had same problem. Solved by changing default language. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

write handler level uppercased to bypass this code 
`strtoupper($handler['level']))`
for example 
`level: INFO`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very very strange. The MonologExtension uses constant() at one point, and it does it like that:

```
constant('Monolog\Logger::'.strtoupper($handler['level']))
```

So basically, it uppercases the given level. Seeing the exception about `::iNFO` not being found does not make sense, unless perhaps you have the mbstring extension enabled with the `mbstring.func_overload` option enabled as well.

Can you check if `ini_get('mbstring.func_overload')` returns 0/null? Otherwise that may be the cause. I really can't think of anything else.

Comment: Error reason: Turkish system language. so in Turkish language "i" upper case "İ" and "I" lowercase "ı". I'm change my system language to English and problem solved. Thanks.